Are comments allowed in credentials file for fstab?
I'm using a credentials file to store samba login information, which I use in /etc/fstab. Is it possible to add comments to that file, so that it ends up something like:
# this is the login info for the remote server
username=value
password=value
domain=value


Try it and let us know!

What operating system are you using? I don't really know, but it isn't impossible that the answer will depend on that.

I'm using Raspberry Pi OS, bullseye version

Comments are not allowed, technically. You can, however, simply add lines that aren't valid, but you'll get errors logged if you enable verbose logging, if this is Linux' mount.cifs utility:
/*
 * Parse a line from the credentials file.  Changes target to first
 * character after '=' on 'line' and returns the value type of the line
 * Returns CRED_UNPARSEABLE on failure or if either parameter is NULL.
 */
static int parse_cred_line(char *line, char **target)
{
    if (line == NULL || target == NULL)
        goto parsing_err;

    /* position target at first char of value */
    *target = strchr(line, '=');
    if (!*target)
        goto parsing_err;
    *target += 1;

    /* tell the caller which value target points to */
    if (strncasecmp("user", line, 4) == 0)
        return CRED_USER;
    if (strncasecmp("pass", line, 4) == 0)
        return CRED_PASS;
    if (strncasecmp("dom", line, 3) == 0)
        return CRED_DOM;

parsing_err:
    return CRED_UNPARSEABLE;
}

Each line in that file must contain a =, and the string before must be user, pass or dom, else the parsing function tells you there's an error.
However, the loop that goes through all lines in the file doesn't really care:
        /* parse next token */
        switch (parse_cred_line(line_buf + i, &temp_val)) {
// …
        case CRED_UNPARSEABLE:
            if (parsed_info->verboseflag)
                fprintf(stderr, "Credential formatted "
                    "incorrectly\n");
            break;
        }

So, you can have lines in there that aren't conforming to the standard.
They are not comment lines, though!
# This line is a parsing error, nothing special about `#`
This line is also a parsing error
#dom=foo is a parsing error as well
So is=this.
Parsing=error!
# The next line is NOT a parsing error, though this is
user=charly
# This next line is still a parsing error:
#user=charly
The last line has probably very unexpected effects, 
so don't start lines with `#`! People will think that # signifies
an actual comment, but what happens here is that there will be a user 
with # in its name.
user=charles #He prefers being called Charles, not Charly.

You really, REALLY shouldn't. Really.
As you can clearly see, the behaviour of this code in the face of invalid data is very ad-hoc, and it's not specified anywhere. So what you put in there that isn't user=username, pass=password or dom=domain and works today might end up in public server logs tomorrow, or simply break the mounting.
In fact, I'm considering sending in a patch to the CIFS utilities to make that happen; I'm spotting multiple problems in that code that might have security implications, and a side effect of fixing that would be really not just continuing when you see an incorrectly formatted line.

Thanks. And especially, thanks for the detail.
